# boost/assign.hpp fails in Xcode 6.3

Tags: c++, boost, xcode6.3

```
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/assign.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost::assign;

template<int N>
struct factorial
{
    enum {
        value = N * factorial<N-1>::value
    };
};

template<>
struct factorial<0>
{
    enum {
        value = 1
    };

};

int main()
{
    typedef std::map<uint64_t, std::string> map_type;

    map_type const map_obj = {
        { 0x0000000000000401, "one"   },
        { 0x0000000000000002, "two"   },
        { 0x0000000000000003, "three" },
        { 0x0000000000000404, "four"  },
        { 0x0000000000000005, "five"  },
    };

    const int mask_value = 0x000000000000FF00;

    auto func = [](const map_type::value_type& p)
                    {
                        std::cout << " value_type.second: " << p.second << "\n";
                        return (p.first & mask_value) != 0;
                    };

    for(const auto&v : map_obj | filtered(func) | map_values)
    {
        std::cout << " Got: " << v <<"\n" ;
    }
    std::cout << " 5!: " << factorial<5>::value << "\n";
}
```

The above example code use to compile in Xcode but in Xcode 6.3 it fails to compile initializer list for map obj in the beginning of main function. There are no complains with boost headers. Any idea, why?

Comment: Next time please at least glance at the post preview before hitting "Ask Question". Yours was unreadable.

Comment: "fails to compile" Should we simply _guess_ at the compilation error? What about your compilation commands?

Comment: It is Xcode - no compilation command. What is unreadable - it is correctly formatted and the question was at the end of the code.!

Comment: Xcode runs a compilation command. As for formatting, yes it is correctly formatted, because I fixed it!! Take a look at the revision history.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh the error was link time error, my boost was built using libc++ not using libstdc++. Switching the library worked.